# Using 2 HTML elements with non-unique ids

Tags: javascript, html

I am using 2 same id's in my HTML file that connect to my JavaScript file and I know this brings up issues because you can't use 2 id's with the same name, but I wanted to see if there's a short way around this?

HTML code below

```html
<div class="txt_field">
  <input type="password" required="" id="id_password">
  <i class="far fa-eye" id="togglePassword"></i>
  <span></span>
  <label>Password</label>
</div>
<div class="txt_field">
  <input type="password" required="" id="id_password">
  <i class="far fa-eye" id="togglePassword"></i>
  <span></span>
  <label>Confirm Password</label>
```

Below is my JavaScript code

```js
const togglePassword1 = document.querySelector('#togglePassword');
  const password = document.querySelector('#id_password');

  togglePassword.addEventListener('click', function (e){
    // toggle the type attribute
    const type = password.getAttribute('type') === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password';
    password.setAttribute('type', type);
    // toggle the eye slash icon
    this.classList.toggle('fa-eye-slash');
});
```

Comment: Very short way around this: don't use duplicate IDs. What even is the point here? If you are going to have multiple things to match, then use a class or any other selector, e.g., select by a data-* property or combinators or a mix.

Comment: Quick way around what? What are you trying to achive?

Comment: No, because a id is a identificador, in this case for the html tag, try with the attribute "name"  and not id. (the attribute name allow has the same name)

Comment: Either suffix ids with a unique number or use class, this is why I tell novices to always use class if possible.

Comment: @zer00ne okay so i edited my html to have id_password_1 and id_password_2 instead of the same name but then how do i select those two in javascript?

Comment: Suffix the id as in `<div id='ID1'></div>` and `<div id='ID2'></div>` is `const password = document.querySelector('#ID1');` and `const password = document.querySelector('#ID2');`

Comment: You can have both a class and an id on the input, so you can select them by class yet distinguish them with id.

Comment: @zer00ne giving me another error that i cant redeclare the block-scoped variable 'password' should i change to password1 and password2?

Comment: Yep, sorry  cut n paste then left to eat real quick.

Comment: I always have the impression that some people think IDs are mandatory in order to access HTML elements from JavaScript. They are not. You're dealing with form elements, why not just `name`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way of doing it without IDs:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function (e){
 if(e.target.classList.contains("far")){
  const inp=e.target.previousElementSibling;
  inp.type=inp.type=="text"?"password":"text";
 }
});
```

```html
<div class="txt_field">
 <input type="password" required="" name="pw1">
 <i class="far">&#x1F441;</i>
 <span></span>
 <label>Password</label>
</div>
<div class="txt_field">
 <input type="password" required="" name="pw2">
 <i class="far">&#x1F441;</i>
 <span></span>
 <label>Confirm Password</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You never ever ever want to use duplicate ids, you could still differentiate between the two if you do

`querySelectorAll("#id_password")`

and then grab index 0 or index 1 according to your correct variable, again **NOT RECOMMENDED** don't use duplicate ids.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely must always use **unique** id attribute values, or you will not have valid HTML (inputs also need a name attribute set if you want them submitted with a form). In your case I would recommend using a common classname to identify which elements will have the desired functionality (i.e. `class="togglePassword"`)

You can explicitly declare exactly which element the toggle will control by adding it's unique id to a data attribute of the toggle, then use that in the event handler to get the element. To make it work smoothly use the id selector string (i.e. `data-toggle="#id_password"`) and pass that to `document.querySelector()`.

In the snippet below, I have also slightly altered the function to insure the eye slash icon is toggled correctly (in sync with input).

```js
const togglePasswords = document.querySelectorAll('.togglePassword');

togglePasswords.forEach(togglePassword => {

  togglePassword.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // get the associated input to toggle
    const pwInput = document.querySelector(this.dataset.toggle)
    // get the toggle direction
    const to_text = pwInput.getAttribute('type') === 'password'
    // toggle the type attribute
    const type = to_text ? 'text' : 'password';
    pwInput.setAttribute('type', type);
    // toggle the eye slash icon (force present when text, absent when password)
    this.classList.toggle('fa-eye-slash', to_text);
  })

})
```

```css
.togglePassword {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="txt_field">
  <input type="password" required="" id="id_password" name="password">
  <i class="far fa-eye togglePassword" data-toggle="#id_password"></i>
  <label for="id_password">Password</label>
</div>
<div class="txt_field">
  <input type="password" required="" id="id_password_repeated" name="password_repeated">
  <i class="far fa-eye togglePassword" data-toggle="#id_password_repeated"></i>
  <label for="id_password_repeated">Confirm Password</label>
</div>
```